# How can I /setblock signs with text in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way in which I can /setblock signs in MCPE, **with text already applied**? I've tried the following but I don't know how to do the actual text:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ standing_sign 0 replace
```

Is what I'm asking possible? and if it is, how can I do this?

---

**Note**: This question is specific to data tags in MCPE/Bedrock Edition to setblock **signs**. I don't know the Java OR MCPE format for putting text in signs. So, how do you use data tags in MCPE, specifically for signs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set sign text, it requires the use of NBT tags. NBT tags are not supported in the current version of Minecraft Bedrock edition. There are plans to introduce this functionality in the future, so your best bet is to wait until then.